# Standard Deviation

Tags: standard-deviation

I really need help with this question. If someone could help me it would be great.

A water ride has the minimum height requirement of 5 feet. The average height of children who visit the park is 4 feet 10 inches, with a standard deviation of 2 inches.

1.) What percentage of the children who go to the park qualify to ride?

Comment: *Hint:* Those children who are one standard deviation above the mean height or taller will be allowed to ride the ride (*4foot10inches + 2inches = 5foot*).  What percentage of data in any normally distributed set will be one standard deviation above the mean or greater?

Answer (score 1):

Alright so by the $68-95-99.7$ rule, we have $32\%$ of people are either shorter than $4'6$ or taller than $5'0$

By symmetry of the bell curve, $\boxed{16\%}$ of kids fall under the taller than $5$ feet category and are eligible for the roller coaster. To be more precise, we can use $68.27-95.45-99.73$ to get $\boxed{15.865\%}$

Comment: Did you read the comment, and consider it, that I left you yesterday?  Is it that you can't answer anything more difficult?  You are enabling users to ask problem statements here at MSE to get there homework done for them by users like you.

Comment: I'm pretty dumb, so yeah. I doubt I can answer hard questions on here @amWhy

Comment: Good questions are not equivalent to hard questions, just to note that.  Good questions can address any level of mathematics,  but we do insist that any question, basic to advanced, who some context in the question post itself:  Where are you stuck?  What definitions apply here? What have you tried, and how far did you get on your own. (No matter whether your attempt succeeded or failed)...What is the source of the question?  When an asker addresses any such questions in the question field, it will most likely be a good question.

Comment: But I've lost count of all the many homework-style questions, absent any thoughts, efforts, attempts, etc from the asker, you've answered....All I do know is that it's been far too many.

Comment: That's alright. Even if they don't benefit, not having put any effort, I do benefit. I learn new things on this site every time I answer a question. @amWhy